# Creating a Handsontable with manual column resize but a constant 100% total width

Tags: handsontable

Is it possible to create a Handsontable that is limited to a width of 100% on column resize, even of the content is long?

```
var table = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: [['short', '<Some long text...>']],
  stretchH: "all",
  colHeaders: true,
  manualColumnResize: true,
  wordWrap: true
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rene/uLLv9wdt/).

To start with, the long content isn't wrapped. But even if the 2 columns are resized to fit the screen, widening the first one again leads to the whole table extending beyond the screen.

(As an aside: it's not quite clear when the `strechH` kicks in, because it doesn't always stretch smaller tables to 100%; and in some cases a new, third header cell even appears mysteriously.)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this for con and row resize

```
manualColumnResize: gridManualColumnResize,
    manualRowResize: gridManualRowResize,
```